# What's a variable in a inner function definition in python?

Tags: python, django, function, class, symbols

There is class definition in django of view in view.generic.base

```
class View(object):
    ...
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        """ 
        Main entry point for a request-response process.
        """
        ...

        def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            self = cls(**initkwargs)
            if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
                self.head = self.get
            self.request = request
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # take name and docstring from class
        update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())

        # and possible attributes set by decorators
        # like csrf_exempt from dispatch
        update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
        return view
```

It should return a function like view(request, *args, **kwargs).
Notice there is a variable in 'def view', which is 'cls'.

Suppose we run:

tmp = View.as_view(), how will tmp(request, *args, **kwargs) know what is the value of cls?

---

### **THIS IS THE SIMPLIFIED SITUATION!!!!!**

Say python code like this:

```
>>> def func1(a):
...     def func2(b):
...         c = a + b
...         print c
...     return func2
... 
>>> func3 = func1(3)
>>> func3(1)
4
>>> func4 = func1(4)
>>> func3(1)
4
>>> func4(1)
5
>>> func3.a=5
>>> func3(1)
4
>>> func1.a=5
>>> func3(1)
4
```

What is 'a' in def of func3 actually and how did func3 get it?

---

Update1:

Thanks for answering. The question was not totally expressed.

I think, when we call func3 = func1(3), we have two objects in the program, code of func1, object(symbol table) of called func1(3).

My questions are:

1. Is there an func2() object produced by calling code func1(), or the value of func3 is just a pointer to a member of the produced func1(3) which is the instruction of func2()?
2. Is the a of calling func3(1) in func1(3), or the object of func2()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain what your code does

```
>>> def func1(a):
...     def func2(b):
...         c = a + b
...         print c
...     return func2
...
```

This will create one function `func1` which return you another function `func2`. `func2` is local for `func1`

```
>>> func3 = func1(3)
```

This will create variable `func3` and value of `func3` is `func2`. So when you print value of `func3` it will return function.

```
>>> func3
<function func2 at 0x7fd29fcb66e0>
```

If you try to access `func3.a` then it will not return you `1` because `a` is not a attribute of `func2`.

```
>>> func3.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'a'
```

`a` is local variable, so you cant access it. When you call `func3`, it will call `func2` with `a` as `1`.

```
>>> func3(1)
4
```

So this will call `func2(1)` where `a` is `3` in local `func2`.

Answer (score 4):

You have created a [closure](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html) by returning a function from another function.

Using your simplified example, any variables that were in scope, and were referenced from your inner function `func2` will remain in scope for as long as `func2` continues to exist.

So any variables declared inside `func1` (including function parameters such as `a`) are always accessible to `func2` even after `func1` ends.

The value that `a` has when `func2` runs will be whatever value you passed to `func1` to produce that particular instance of `func2`

Answer (score 1):

I've run the same python program with some changes :

```
>>> def func1(a):
...     def func2(b):
...             c = a + b
...             print c
...             print a
...             print b
...     return func2
... 
>>> func3 = func1(3)
>>> func3(1)
4
3
1
```

1. First of all when you call fun1(3), then the fun1 returns fun2, something like this

---

```
def fun2(b):
    c = 3 + b
    print c
    print 3
    print b
```

---

2. Now, when you call function func3(1), you are effectively calling func2(1)

It's the way it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

For start, there is nothing recursive going on here, I guess you mean inner function definition. Inner function has access to surrounding scope (which is also called a closure). When you get your copy of function `func3` it will have access to variables defined in outer function including parameter it's been called with